# cant return a sorted iqueryable of datetime

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework

keep getting the wrong result when I try to return this list of dates

**Updated**

```
  Private Shared Function GetDistinctDates(ByRef ctx As ToolkitEntities,
                                             ByVal symbol As String,
                                             ByVal interval As Integer,
                                             Optional isRangeProj As Boolean = False) As  List(Of Date)
        Dim numDates As Integer = 0
        If isRangeProj = True Then
            numDates = 3
        Else
            numDates = TakeValue(interval)
        End If

        Dim dates = (From data In ctx.tsintracharts
                     Where data.Symbol = symbol
                     Select data.Date).Distinct().ToList()

        'Dim datelist As IQueryable(Of Date) = dates.OrderByDescending(Function(o) o).Take(numDates)
        Return dates
    End Function
```

No ordering occurs, the whole list of dates is returned

I've ordered by date before, both using the function syntax and by putting OrderBy before the Select in the linq statement. I am simply trying to return the latest three dates in the distinct list of dates.

However, if I move the Order By into the LINQ statement no ordering occurs

```
  Dim dates = (From data In ctx.tsintracharts
                    Where data.Symbol = symbol
                    Order By data.Date Descending
                    Select data.Date
                    ).Distinct()
```

and returning dates.Take(numDates) does in fact return only three dates. The problem is they are always the oldest and I need the latest.

Comment: for starters it should only be returning three dates (in the routine im testing it in) and its returning all 35 dates. Im also not sure how to order ascending whe using the function syntax like this, if this is even a more efficient way than having the OrderBy in the LINQ statement itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, pretty lame but it works. Anyone who can better this method would be my hero as I'm certain there is a better way to complete this than the methodology this answer depicts.

```
Private Shared Function GetDistinctDates(ByRef ctx As ToolkitEntities,
                                             ByVal symbol As String,
                                             ByVal interval As Integer,
                                             Optional isRangeProj As Boolean = False) As List(Of Date)
        Dim numDates As Integer = 0
        If isRangeProj = True Then
            numDates = 3
        Else
            numDates = TakeValue(interval)
        End If

        Dim dates As List(Of Date) = (From d In ctx.tsintracharts
                                      Where d.Symbol = symbol
                                      Select d.Date).Distinct().ToList()

        Dim datelist As New List(Of Date)
        For x As Integer = 1 To dates.Count
            If x > (dates.Count - numDates) Then
                datelist.Add(dates(x - 1))
            End If
        Next
        Return datelist
    End Function
```